# Unable to get idmap_ad to work with Ubuntu 12.04 and Samba 4

Tags: active-directory, samba

I am trying to get the uid and gid mapping I have set in active directory to copy from there to my already existing Ubuntu boxes that I am adding to a Windows 2008 Domain Controller. We are trying to get all machines joined, and since the machines already have these mappings form OpenLDAP, getting them to copy is very important. I am using Samba4, Winbind, Ubuntu 12.04.

smb.conf:

```
[global]
security = ads
realm = DOMAIN.NET
password server = dc01.domain.net
workgroup = DOMAIN
#idmap uid = 1000-99999
#idmap gid = 1000-99999
idmap config *:backend = tdb
idmap config *:range = 70001-80000
idmap config DOMAIN:backend = ad
idmap config DOMAIN:range = 500-40000
winbind nss info = rfc2307
winbind separator = +
winbind enum users = no
winbind enum groups = no
winbind use default domain = yes
template homedir = /home/%U
template shell = /bin/bash
client use spnego = yes
domain master = no
```

krb5.conf:

```
[logging]
    default = FILE:/var/log/krb5.log
[libdefaults]
    allow_weak_crypto = true
    ticket_lifetime = 24000
    default_realm = DOMAIN.NET
    default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac
    default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac
[realms]
    DOMAIN.NET = {
        kdc = DC01.DOMAIN.NET
        admin_server = DC01.DOMAIN.NET
        default_domain = DOMAIN
}
[domain_realm]
    .domain.net = DOMAIN.NET
    domain.net = DOMAIN.NET
```

nsswitch.conf

```
# pre_auth-client-config # passwd:         compat
passwd: compat winbind
# pre_auth-client-config # group:          compat
group: compat winbind
# pre_auth-client-config # shadow:         compat
shadow: compat winbind

hosts:          files dns wins
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

# pre_auth-client-config # netgroup:       nis
netgroup: nis
```

When I add the idmap config DOMAIN:backend = ad lines, I cannot ssh into the machine with a domain account, only local. If I comment those lines out, I can SSH with domain accounts and groups are read. Both config allow me to get returns from wbinfo, in both getent only returns local accts as well. I am beyond stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Unix attributes have to be set on the Domain Users group for the AD users to be pulled in. Then, anyone with the Unix fields defined can be queried.